# How to replace an input string to file?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a config file that need to replace DBpass and host ip when deploy

some code look like this:
`{DBPASS}@{ip}`

I create a scripts file to replace them like this

```
echo "Host IP?"
read ip
sed -i 's/{ip}/$ip/g' abc.conf
echo "DB pass?"
read dbpass
sed -i 's/{DBPASS}/$dbpass/g' abc.conf
```

and it turn out to be like this in config file
`$dbpass@$ip`

So how can I make the sed command in shellscripts replace the word I input before.

Answer (score 2):

change the single quotes `'` into double quotes `"` in your sed commands, so that the shell variables can be expanded.